# Subusers: API key VS on-behalf-of for SendGrid V3 API Requests

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

I'm confused as to how best interact with SendGrid subusers using the API.
So far I have been using on-behalf-of for all my requests.
However I've now come across an endpoint that does not accept on-behalf-of:
POST /v3/verified_senders
for creating Single Senders.

So it seems I will instead have to start creating an API key for all subusers, which I haven't been doing.

So that begs the question: why use on-behalf-of in the first place? Why not use the subusers API key in all requests?

Thanks!

I tried a POST request to POST /v3/verified_senders
using on-behalf-of as a header but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this API endpoint does work with 'on-behalf-of', it just doesn't say this in the documentation. I have asked SendGrid to update this.